# iOS >> Drag and Drop Issue >> UIView Returns to Original Position

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, drag-and-drop

I have 4 UIImageViews set in IB. I also have a UILabel describing the status (as described in code below).
I use the touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnd methods to capture the object move as follow:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch* aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView* aView = [aTouch view];
    if (aView != self.view) {
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:aView];
        self.statusLabel.text = @"You're Dragging...";
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch* aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView* aView = [aTouch view];
    if (aView != self.view) {
        aView.center = [aTouch locationInView:self.view];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.statusLabel.text = @"At Ease";
}
```

The problem is that after I move (in the simulator) one of the UIImageViews they "jump" back to their original position as its set in IB instead of remaining where I dropped them.

Why does it happen?
How can I "capture" the UIImageView new position at "touchesEnd" and avoid this "jump"?

P.S. I noticed that if I don't update the label at "touchesEnd" the UIImageView remains at its last position until I click on another UIImageView; what's going on over here?

Comment: The code looks and runs fine in quicky mockup I ran (although I might track which view is being moved and set its final location based on the `touchesEnded` location).  Are you sure you are not setting the moving view's center somewhere else in your code, or reloading the entire view from the nib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems to be correct..you just try it after unchecking auto layout ...
Later i found author has posted the answer himself...so,sorry for this post..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thanks json; never-mind the late reply, I'm glad to see somebody else had the same issue with the same solution... Any idea what's next? Does it mean that if I want to do Drag&Drop I cannot use Autolayout?

Comment: @OhadRegev   thanks..i will let you know...because apple must have an option to use it with auto layout..lets find that now..and have you used position locking of images..??

Comment: json, I haven't used position locking of images. I'm not familiar with that... BTW - I tried using UIGestureRecognizer and it's working OK (I still need to learn it better, but it's quite cool...). anyway, thanks again for the assistance and willingness!

Answer (score 0):

I un-checked the "Auto Layout" checkbox in IB and it worked fine. 
That can't be the "best practice" to do that... but it works.